# Is it possible to catch the user respose to a FB event Invitation and redirect the user to my page/app?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Is it possible to catch the user respose to a FB event Invitation and redirect the user to my page/app ?

I am using c# to create the FB event invitation.

Tnx
Aylon

Answer (score 0):

Aylon

If a user is responding to the request from your app or website you can just add a javascript redirect.

If the user is responding to the request within facebook, you will not be able to catch or control the response in any way, other than read the response in the graph api.

Comment: In the second option (within facebook) , I understand that you mean to read the response after and analyse it, right ?

Comment: correct.  You will only be able to read, you will not be able to redirect the user.